# React JS, entire react component renders two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The below API call fetches data from server 2 times causing my react components to render 2 time to DOM ,

How can I prevent this behavior ? I hope I may need to use await function

```
export default function SimpleCard() {
  const [posts,setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    let endpoint = '/api/post/';
    apiService(endpoint).then(data=>setPosts(data))
},[]);



  return (
    <Grid >
    {console.log(posts)}


    </Grid>
  );
}
```

API.SERVICE.JS

```
import { CSRF_TOKEN } from "./csrf_token.js"

function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.status === 204) {
    return '';
  } else if (response.status === 404) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return response.json();
  }

}

function apiService(endpoint, method, data) {
  // D.R.Y. code to make HTTP requests to the REST API backend using fetch
  const config = {
    method: method || "GET",
    body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  };
  return fetch(endpoint, config)
           .then(handleResponse)
           .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

export { apiService };
```

Comment: Looks valid. One is initial render. The other is the effect of `setPosts`. why would you expect only one render ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The map function loops the same array 2 times, how can I prevent it ?

Comment: "The same array" meaning what? The first render will be on an empty array, the second will be after the async request returns (assuming it's async).

Comment: same array means 'posts', the 2 looping causes array objects to render to screen 2 times

Comment: We dn see what you picture in your mind unless you show it. can you update the question with some output and from where is it you think is rendering twice ?

Comment: It *will* render twice: once with the initial, empty array; once with the data after the async call returns. If you don't do anything to handle rendering differently before the data is poopulated that's just the way it works. If you're claiming it's rendering with the data twice you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @DaveNewton I hope I did't use async/await request

Comment: Are you sure the problem don't come from the parent component? Could you give more details about the parent?

Comment: @Alexandre parent component is my main function,and it render only once, Please check my updated question I have added my API fetch function

Comment: I don't understand--that's asynchronous. The data comes after the first render.

Comment: But is you problem to get as output `[]` and then `['post1', 'post2']` because if it is the case it is normal, as explained by @DaveNewton

Comment: @Alexandre your finding was correct, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above component `('<SimpleCard/>')` was called by the parent component 2 times.

Accidently I listed `('<SimpleCard/>')` in parent component. And react router initial page was `('<SimpleCard/>')` itself, when I removed `('<SimpleCard/>')` from main function it worked fine.

```
function Base() {
    return (

        <React.Fragment>
            <ButtonAppBar/>

            <SimpleCard/>             
            <Route exact path="/" component={SimpleCard}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>

        </React.Fragment>
        )
}

export default Base
```